# How to do the best PhD , brief tips to a new phD student?

Tags: phd, research-process, graduate-school

I am a graduate student who has been  doing masters for a year and I am moving to PhD program in Chemical Engineering in the same University. My work is mostly computational , molecular modeling. My University is fairly reputed(70- 80 on US news) and my advisor is known in his field ,but our research group is small(3-4 graduate students).There are many postdocs and researchers on this website, As  a new phD student, if you could give some tips on how to do the best phD, to do good after my phD and stay in research field next, that would greatly helpful to many students like me .

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid this question is much too broad (per the [help/dont-ask]). There are entire books that address this question (e.g.: [The Unwritten Rules of PhD Research](https://www.amazon.com/Unwritten-Rules-Research-Study-Skills/dp/0335237029)).